# Высота UITableVIew програмно (autolayout)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

Внутри ScrollView находятся два Label (многосторочные), а ниже него TableView (в котором количество строк так же может быть разным).

Высота обоих Label и TableView - не заданы.
Высота строк у TableView - фиксированная и равна 50.0f.

У всех аутлетов заданы констранты на отступы друг от друга - в частности сверху и снизу, включая View контейнера, в котором они все располагаются.

В итоге: оба Label скролятся, а TableView получается с высотой 0. Её видно только если высоту таблицы задать явно. Количество строк TableView при этом определяется корректно.

Как программно можно задавать высоту самой TableView, чтобы ее стало видно ("высота строки" х "количество ячеек")?

Или же можно поступить как-то иначе?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ячейки у Вас разного размера или все одинаковой высоты?

Comment: Высота ячеек в данном случае не динамическая - одинаковая.

Answer (score 1):

Подсказали на англоязычном stackoverflow.

1. Необходимо задать constraint для высоты таблицы. Я выбрал "Height >=0", чтобы таблицу было не видно если она не заполняется.
2. В .h добавить `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *myTableHeight;` и связать строчку с только что добавленной constraint через storyboard.
3. В **viewDidLayoutSubviews**: `self.myTableHeight.constant = self.myTableView.contentSize.height;`